# FullCalendar JSON Event Source Problem

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

I have this problem of my FullCalendar not showing any events on IE or Mozilla. It works well with Chrome though. I have a JSON source generated by the following php code:

$name,
      'title' => strtoupper("$name-$cycleno"),
      'start' => "$year-$month-$day",
      'url' => "viewstat.php?year=$year&month=$month&day=$day&name=$name&cycleno=$cycleno" 
    ); 
 }

echo json_encode($event_array);
closedir($handle);
?>

I've validated the JSON with JSONLint. But still I have no clue as to why this is happening. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $month had the values jan,feb,mar,.. instead of '01','02','03',... Somehow Chrome was able to display it but not IE and Mozilla. I changed the values to numerics and got it working..!

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the content type header for json

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks xaoc, but I figured out the problem. The $month had the values jan,feb,mar,.. instead of '01','02','03',... Somehow Chrome was able to display it but not IE and Mozilla. I changed the values to numerics and got it working..!